# Substitution of variables in Calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I believe it is well established that (sin(x))' = cos(x).

If we let x = 2n, then substituting, we have sin(2n)' = cos(2n). However, the chain rule suggests otherwise: sin(2n)' = 2cos(2n).

In fact, graphically, we see that the chain rule is indeed correct, and the substitution of variables yields an incorrect answer.

What is wrong with this substitution that makes it a false statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dx} \sin (x) =\cos(x)
\end{eqnarray*}
When you substitute $x=2n$ you get 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{d(\color{red}{2}n)} \sin (2n) =\cos(2n)
\end{eqnarray*}
Can you spot where the "extra" factor of $2$ comes from ?